# Elements hidden with overflow still accessible on android

Tags: android, css, facebook-comments, coverflow

I have a Facebook-comments widget contained within a parent div witch cuts it of vertically using overflow hidden. I have set it up in that manner so that I can start out showing only part of the content and then expand the parent container with jQuery.

This works great on every major browser (inculding safari for iPhone), however in Android (tested on Android 4.0, not sure on browser version) content outside the overflowed div, while still not being visible, is accessible. User can click links they cannot see, clearly an unwanted behavior.

My HTML:

```
<div class="pageBlock column5050 column2">          
  <div style="" class="ext_container">
    <div data-mobile="false" data-width="" data-num-posts="10" data-href="http://na.se/redesign2012/kundcenter" class="fb-comments  fb_iframe_widget">
      <span style="height: 1049px; width: 550px;">
        <iframe scrolling="no" id="fcb3ba7898c46" name="f169222f1ff27fe" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 1049px; width: 550px;" class="fb_ltr " src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?api_key=113851685335230&amp;channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D8%23cb%3Df12db7f9bc71f98%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fna.se%252Ffb9561675e1892%26domain%3Dna.se%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fna.se%2Fredesign2012%2Fkundcenter&amp;locale=sv_SE&amp;mobile=false&amp;numposts=10&amp;sdk=joey&amp;width=550"></iframe>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fb_expand_btn expand_btn">
    <span class="expand_capt">Visa fler...</span>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    [...]js/jQuery to expand/contract "ext_container"[..]
  </script>

</div>
```

Everything inside "ext_container" is generated by the facebook comments widget and I have limited control over the HTML since I'm using a third party CMS.

I use the following CSS

```
.fb-comments {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.fb-comments span, .fb-comments iframe {
  width: 100% !important;
}


.ext_container {
  position: relative;
  height: 440px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 20px 20px;
}

.fb_expand_btn.expand_btn {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

My script alters the ext_container height only.

I set ext_container to position:relative because of a IE7 bug where it would ignore my overflow:hidden.

Finally, the 100% width are there because a have a fully fluid layout.

Anyway, I've tried to find any reference to the behavior described above but to n avail, would really appreciate if someone have come across this and have a solution.

Comment: i'm having the same problem on Nexus 4, using overflow: scroll... I could fix it using the other elements absolute positioning, but that hack is ugly as hell.. Trying to find another way though.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the iframe is getting a browser default width.
Try setting the width attribute of the iframe, rather just setting the width style.

In other words, try giving the iframe the attribute,

> width="550"

Iframes and css don't always play nice, especially when it comes to overflow.
You may also benefit from setting the height attribute.

Comment: The width works just fine though.

Anyway I can't set the actual width/height values on the iFrame since it's genereated by the facebook sdk, hence the need for setting the css-width (and even making it !important).

You did give me the idea to try and target the actual height of the iFrame instead of the container, might work...

Comment: Instead of setting css-height of the container I now tried to set the height (not css) on the div with my script. It look fine, but content outside the iFrame was still accessible, so no success there.